# ¿Se usa "tata" como "tía" en España?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, españa, parentesco

La pregunta de hoy tiene tintes familiares. Resulta que mi mujer siempre se ha referido a algunas tías suyas usando la voz *tata*, que yo desconocía y que con el tiempo simplemente asocié con el significado de "tía". Ella siempre habla de "la tata Carmen" y "la tata María". Incluso en el caso de nuestros hijos, ellos ya empiezan a referirse a estas dos personas usando *tata* como si fuese un título más que un parentesco.

Sin embargo, ayer me dio por buscar la palabra en el diccionario y me encuentro esto:

> **[tato<sup>1</sup>, ta](https://dle.rae.es/?id=ZFvwlG9)**
>
> `Del lat.`*`tata`*`'padre'.`
>
> 1. m. y f. afect. coloq. **hermano** (‖ persona con el mismo padre y la misma madre que otra).
> 2. f. coloq. Niñera y, por ext., muchacha de servicio.

¿En qué quedamos entonces? ¿*Tata* es "hermana" o "tía"? Le pregunto a mi mujer y resulta que ella se sabía estas dos acepciones de *tata*, solo que ella usa la palabra para sus tías. Entiendo entonces que lo que ha pasado es que para mi suegra, sus hermanas sí que eran sus *tatas*, y cuando ella decía "vamos a ir a ver a la tata Carmen", lo que quería decir era que iban a ver a su hermana (uso correcto), pero como decía "la tata" en vez de "mi tata", se quedó la palabra "tata" como una especie de título para dicha persona, de modo que mi mujer y sus hermanos siguieron usando *tata* aunque para ellos significaba "tía". Obviamente este uso se restringe al ámbito familiar dado que se usa de forma cariñosa, pero nunca hacia afuera de la familia.

Una vez contado este cuento familiar, toca preguntar. Esto que pasa con la familia de mi mujer puede haber ocurrido en más familias, pero ¿hasta qué punto? ¿Se usa en algún sitio de España la voz *tata* con el significado de "tía" de forma común? ¿O es este caso endémico de la familia de mi mujer?

Comment: Yo soy de Córdoba (de España) y en mi familia he visto usar _tata_ y _tate_ para hermana o hermano **mayor**; algo parecido a [_onee-chan_](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=onee-chan)/[_onii-chan_](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Onii-Chan) en japonés. Yo creo que, al final, la _tata_ es la que cuida de un pequeño: lo normal es que sea una familiar mayor (hermana, tía o abuela) pero también puede ser pagada. Es una voz sencilla de decir para niños muy pequeños.

Comment: A mi me a pasado k conozco familiares k le a llamado a sus tías tata cuando eran más pequeños por no saber decir Tita pero al tiempo fue creciendo ya le llamaba por Tita.

Comment: Curiosamente oí esta palabra ayer para la primera vez en la radio en Nuevo Mexico, USA, y hoy veo una explicación!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**The free dictionary**](https://es.thefreedictionary.com/tata) define *tata*:

> (Del lat. tata.)
>   1. *s. f. familiar* Voz infantil con que se designa a la **niñera**.
>   2. *familiar* Voz infantil para referirse a la **tía o a la hermana**.
>   3. *s. m. Amér. familiar* Voz con la que se designa al **padre** y, de forma ocasional, al **abuelo**.

Es decir, que parece que, según los usos y costumbres de la zona / familia, etc., **tata** puede utilizarse para referirse a la *niñera*, *tía* o *hermana*, y **tato** al *padre* o *abuelo*. Esto me hace pensar que, dado que la mayoría de las definiciones incluyen lo de "voz infantil", que es utilizada por los niños para la(s) persona(s) que les cuidan (diferentes de la madre).

Comment: He buscado las fuentes de las que se nutre _The free dictionary_ de la compañia Farlex Inc. y no he encontrado nada aparte del _Disclaimer: All Content is provided “as is” without warranty of any kind. Farlex does not make any warranty whatsoever, express or implied, as to the accuracy or completeness of the Content or the results to be obtained from using the Content, and Farlex will not be responsible for any claims ..._ Me pregiunto: ¿Qué fiabilidad tiene este sitio?

Comment: Esto coincide con mi uso personal. Mi *tata* es una hermana de mi madre que vivía con nosotros cuando yo era muy pequeño, y que ejercía como segunda madre para mí. A veces, también una prima varios años mayor que yo. En cualquier caso, una mujer de mi familia que podía, en ocasiones, cuidar de mí.

Comment: Para mí una tata siempre ha sido una chica que se encarga de cuidar o estar al tanto de los niños. Si los recursos económicos lo permiten, se puede contratar a una persona ajena al círculo familiar y de amigos; en caso contrario se encargaban las hermanas mayores o primas o tías.